# Robotium: SVG/Bitmap NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, svg, bitmap, robotium

I'm testing a part of this Android application using Robotium which lets the user doodle on the canvas. The strokes are stored as SVG elements (a custom class) in a `java.util.List`. I simulate a line drawing gesture via `solo.drag` and print the Generation IDs of the two bitmaps - before drawing and after drawing. The generation IDs are different from each other, which means the bitmap has been modified. But the SVG element list is null (I get a `NullPointerException` at the second-last line of the following snippet). How is this so?

Following is the code:

```
Bitmap testBitmap = (([package.name].MainActivity) solo.getCurrentActivity()).getPaintView().getBitmap();
int emptyBitmapGenID = testBitmap.getGenerationId();
Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), ""+emptyBitmapGenID);

solo.drag(strokeFromX, strokeToX, strokeFromY, strokeToY, strokeStepCount);
solo.clickOnScreen(10, 10); //To release the touch

int strokedBitmapGenID = testBitmap.getGenerationId();
Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), ""+strokedBitmapGenID);

solo.waitForActivity(MainActivity.class);
List<[package.name].SVG.SVG_Element> elementList = (([package.name].MainActivity) solo.getCurrentActivity()).getRenderManager().getCurrDisplayList(false);

if(elementList==null)
{
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "SVG element list null!");
}

Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), ""+elementList.toString());
[package.name].SVG.SVG_Stroke stroke = ([package.name].SVG.SVG_Element)elementList.get(0);
Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), stroke.toString());
```

This problem arises only some of the times. Following is the log when it runs fine:

```
06-19 11:22:43.210: D/[package.name].test.Utils(11520): 31
06-19 11:22:46.435: D/[package.name].test.Utils(11520): 41
06-19 11:22:46.435: D/[package.name].test.Utils(11520): [<g class='stroke' id='520c7ff6-1800-4f0c-a544-8be164a6eeca' transform='matrix(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0)'><path d='M 255.40 138.30 L 259.39 143.62 L 263.38 148.94 L 267.37 154.26 L 271.36 159.57 L 275.35 164.89 L 279.34 170.21 L 283.33 175.53 L 287.32 180.85 L 291.31 186.17 L 295.30 191.49 L 299.29 196.81 L 303.29 202.13 L 307.28 207.45 L 311.27 212.77 L 315.26 218.09 L 319.25 223.40 L 323.24 228.72 L 327.23 234.04 L 331.22 239.36 L 335.21 244.68 L 339.20 250 L 343.19 255.32 L 347.18 260.64 L 351.17 265.96 L 355.16 271.28 L 359.15 276.60 L 363.14 281.91 L 367.13 287.23 L 371.13 292.55 L 375.12 297.87 L 379.11 303.19 L 383.10 308.51 L 387.09 313.83 L 391.08 319.15 L 395.07 324.47 L 399.06 329.79 L 403.05 335.11 L 407.04 340.43 L 411.03 345.74 L 415.02 351.06 L 419.01 356.38 L 423.00 361.70 L 426.99 367.02 L 430.98 372.34 L 434.97 377.66 L 438.97 382.98 L 442.96 388.30 L 446.95 393.62 L 450.94 398.94 L 454.93 404.26 L 458.92 409.57 L 462.91 414.89 L 466.90 420.21 L 470.89 425.53 L 474.88 430.85 L 478.87 436.17 L 482.86 441.49 L 486.85 446.81 L 490.84 452.13 L 494.83 457.45 L 498.82 462.77 L 502.81 468.09 L 506.81 473.40 L 510.80 478.72 L 514.79 484.04 L 518.78 489.36 L 522.77 494.68 L 526.76 500 L 530.75 505.32 L 534.74 510.64 L 538.73 515.96 L 542.72 521.28 L 546.71 526.60 L 550.70 531.91 L 554.69 537.23 L 558.68 542.55 L 562.67 547.87 L 566.66 553.19 L 570.65 558.51 L 574.65 563.83 L 578.64 569.15 L 582.63 574.47 L 586.62 579.79 L 590.61 585.11 L 594.60 590.43 L 598.59 595.74 L 602.58 601.06 L 606.57 606.38 L 610.56 611.70 L 614.55 617.02 L 618.54 622.34 L 622.53 627.66 L 626.52 632.98 L 630.51 638.30 L 634.50 643.62 L 638.49 648.94 L 642.49 654.26 L 646.48 659.57 L 650.47 664.89 ' stroke='black' stroke-width='6' fill='none' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-opacity='1'/></g>]
```

Comment: Can you add in the output of logcat?

Comment: I've added the logcat output in the question description itself. As I mentioned there, this issue is arising only rarely, the code works fine most of the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was resolved after I updated Robotium to version 5.2.1. I had been using version 5.0.1 earlier.